# Can I Use Query Method in Dapper To Insert And Update Rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dapper

I'm trying to find out whether it is possible to use Query method in Dapper to insert and update rows since I want to return an object after applying insert and update actions.

I could not find any remarkable answers for that so I just tried that:

```
public async Task<Hotel> CreateHotel(Hotel hotel)
    {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO Hotels" +
                    " (name, city)" +
                    " VALUES (@name, @city)";

        var newHotel = new Hotel()
        {
            Name = hotel.Name,
            City = hotel.City
        };

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            return (Hotel)await connection.QueryAsync<Hotel>(sql, newHotel);
        }
    }
```

But that gives that error: *System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EmptyPartition`1[HotelFinder.Entities.Hotel]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HotelFinder.Entities.Hotel]'.*

Do you know how I can fix this or is that completely wrong?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? An insert statement does not return any rows, so you will need to modify the query to return the newly inserted row. How to do that can vary depending on server. Also, `QueryAsync` returns an `IEnumerable`, not a single value, so you're missing a call to `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It looks like I lack some fundamental knowledge. I’m using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use the `OUTPUT` clause in order to return rows from an insert statement.

Second, `QueryAsync` will return an `IEnumerable<Hotel>` and not a `Hotel`, so you won't be able to cast it.

Put together, it would look like this

```cs
public async Task<Hotel> CreateHotel(Hotel hotel)
{
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Hotels" +
                " (name, city)" +
                " OUTPUT inserted.name, inserted.city" +
                " VALUES (@name, @city)";

    var newHotel = new Hotel()
    {
        Name = hotel.Name,
        City = hotel.City
    };

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
    {
        return (await connection.QueryAsync<Hotel>(sql, newHotel)).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the OUTPUT clause. So do we need to use this with Query method then? For example can we do the same with Execute method?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the OUTPUT clause btw. I think the docs are a bit complicated. That's why I wanted to ask it, instead of doing it on my own.

Comment: Execute does not return a dataset, only the number of rows being returned. You could use output with it, but it'd be pointless since the result would be discarded.